# if the Hilbert polynomial of coherent sheaf is constant number,then locally free?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, coherent-sheaves, moduli-space, hilbert-polynomial

I'm reading "The Geometry of Moduli Spaces of Sheaves" (Huybrechts Lehn).

I want to prove [$\operatorname{Quot}_{X/S}(H,l)=\operatorname{Grass}_S(H,l)$]where $X=S$ and $l$ is a number.

Let $T$ be an $S$-scheme and $[\rho:H_T \rightarrow F]\in Q(T)$ where $F$ is flat over $T$ with Hilbert polynomial $P=l$,
then $F$ is locally free with rank $l$?

Answer (score 2):

In fact *any* flat coherent sheaf is locally free; see [Tag 00NX](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00NX) implication $(1) \Rightarrow (6)$ for the corresponding algebra statement.

Thus, if $\mathscr F$ is flat over $T$, then $\mathscr F$ is locally free over $T$. But because $X_T \to T$ is an isomorphism, we conclude that $\mathscr F$ is locally free on $X_T$ (rather than on $T$). This is the step for which we crucially need that $X = S$.

By assumption, the Hilbert polynomial of each fibre $\mathscr F|_{X_t} = \mathscr F \otimes_{\mathcal O_T} \kappa(t)$ is $\ell$ . Hence, $\mathscr F \otimes_{\mathcal O_T} \kappa(t)$ is an $\ell$-dimensional vector space over $\kappa(t)$. It is then easy to see that the rank of $\mathscr F$ at $t$ is $\ell$.

(Note that the fibres of $X_T \stackrel \sim\to T$ are just points, so for any coherent sheaf $\mathscr F$ on $T$, the Hilbert polynomial of the fibre $\mathscr F|_{X_t} = \mathscr F \otimes_{\mathcal O_T} \kappa(t)$ has degree $\leq 0$, i.e. is constant. This corresponds to the fact that coherent sheaves on the spectrum of a field are just finite-dimensional vector spaces, so the only numerical invariant is their dimension.)

(Note that the rank is a priori only *locally* constant. But you assume that the Hilbert polynomial is constant, which forces the rank to be constant.)

---

**Remark.** Of course the situation is different once we start considering Quot schemes $\mathfrak Quot_{X/S}$ where $X$ is no longer equal to $S$: then $\mathscr F$ is a sheaf on $X_T$ which is only flat over $T$, so the above method does not give us much.

Comment: Sorry,I don't understand the relation between "the rank of F" and "Hilbert polynomial of F".And is the x in X?what is the rank of F at x?F is on $X_T$.

Comment: And why F is flat over X if X=S?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't terribly clear. I tried to clarify things a bit more.

Comment: I could understand much more than before thanks to your nice answer.But I still can't understand why "the Hilbert polynomial of each fibre $F|_{X_t}$is just $l$".

Comment: @8Frog: That's the assumption you put on your sheaf $\mathscr F$. You write "$\mathscr F$ is flat over $T$ with Hilbert polynomial $\ell$". What you really mean is each fibre $\mathscr F|_{X_t}$ has Hilbert polynomial $\ell$. There is no such thing as the Hilbert polynomial of $\mathscr F$; the definition of Hilbert polynomial uses dimension of vector spaces, which only works if you are working over a field. Thus, we can only talk about the Hilbert polynomial of the sheaf $\mathscr F|_{X_t}$ on $X_t$ (which is a variety over $\operatorname{Spec} \kappa(t)$). (In our case, $X_t$ is a point.)